# Several Shared layouts for several sidebars

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I'm new to MVC 4 and I'm currently contemplating on what should I do.

**CURRENT CODE**

I made several SHARED layouts for each type of user. So I now have, _AdminLayout.cshtml for the Admin's sidebar, _FacultyLayout.cshtml for Faculty, and _StudentLayout.cshtml

**PROBLEM**

I have several types of users: Admin, Student, and Faculty. The content of the sidebar changes depending on which type of user is logged in.

***Are there any other solutions for this?***

I was planning to put all the sidebars in one SHARED LAYOUT but MVC 4 doesn't have Controllers for Shared Layouts unlike in Web Forms Master Pages, there is a Codebehind file. I'm just trying to shorten my code and lessen the redundancy between the **3 SHARED LAYOUTS** that I currently have.

Comment: You could have one layout and the use `@Html.Action()` to generate the sidebar which would return the appropriate partial view of the sidebar based on the users role.

Comment: Could you help me via pseudo code? I'm really new to MVC 4 haha this is my first project @StephenMuecke

Comment: Sure. How do you currently determine the role of the user?

Comment: After the user successfully logs in, I query the ROLE of the user that has the username that was inputted in the login page.

In Web Forms, I put all my sidebars in divs and are hidden on a single Master Page. In the code behind of the master page, I just handle it by setting the visibility to true if it matches the queried user role. I'm still not sure on its procedure in MVC :( @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one single layout and use `@Html.Action()` to render the sidebar as a partial view depending on the role of the user. This could go in a `BaseController` from which all other controlles inherit, or in a separate controller (say) LayoutController

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult SideBar()
{
  var role = ... // your code for getting the users role
  if (role == "Admin")
  {
    return PartialView("_AdminSideBar");
  }
  else if (role == "Faculty")
  {
    return PartialView("_FacultySideBar");
  }
  else if ..........
}
```

and then create a associated partial views `_AdminSideBar.cshtml`, `_FacultySideBar.cshtml` etc.

Then in the Layout Page

```
......
<div id="sidebar">
  @{ Html.RenderAction("", ""); }
</div>
```

Comment: In layman's terms, what's the difference between a controller and a base controller? Haha

Comment: You will notice that all your controllers inherit from `Controller` - e.g. `public class YourController : Controller { ... }`. Its common to create a `BaseController` for common code - `public class BaseController : Controller { ... }` and then all your controllers inherit from that - `public class YourController : BaseController { ... }`